# Removing duplicate subtrees from CONNECT-BY query in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a heirarchical table in the format

```
CREATE TABLE tree_hierarchy (
  id        NUMBER (20)
 ,parent_id NUMBER (20)
);


INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO tree_hierarchy (id, parent_id) VALUES (9, 4);
```

When I run the Query:-

```
SELECT id,parent_id,
  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF leaf,
  LEVEL,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(id, '/') Path,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(parent_id, '/') Parent_Path
FROM tree_hierarchy
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF<>0
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = PARENT_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ID;
```

Result I am Getting is like this:-

```
"ID"    "PARENT_ID" "LEAF"  "LEVEL" "PATH"  "PARENT_PATH"

9            4         1       3    "/2/4/9"  "/1/2/4"

9            4         1       2     "/4/9"     "/2/4"

9            4         1       1      "/9"      "/4"
```

But I need an Oracle Sql Query That gets me only this

```
"ID"    "PARENT_ID" "LEAF"  "LEVEL" "PATH"  "PARENT_PATH"

9            4         1       3    "/2/4/9"  "/1/2/4"
```

This is a simpler example I have more that 1000 records in such fashion.When I run the above query,It is generating many duplicates.Can any one give me a generic query that will give complete path from leaf to root with out duplicates.Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 5):

The root node in finite hierarchy must be always known.
According to the definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure
the root node is a node  that has no parents. 
To check if a given node is a root node, take "parent_id" and check in the table if exists a record with this id.
The query might look like this:

```
SELECT id,parent_id,
  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF leaf,
  LEVEL,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(id, '/') Path,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(parent_id, '/') Parent_Path
FROM tree_hierarchy th
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF<>0
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = PARENT_id
START WITH not exists (
      select 1 from tree_hierarchy th1 
      where th1.id = th.parent_id
  )
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ID;
```

Comment: You can make it simple by `START WITH parent_id is null`. It may not help this question in particular, but definitely, it makes sense more.

Answer (score 0):

You should point the id patently to build the path for. Now your query is building the path for all leaves which satisfy your condition. You need to use "start with" Let's try it like this:

```sql
SELECT id,parent_id,
  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF leaf,
  LEVEL,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(id, '/') Path,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(parent_id, '/') Parent_Path
FROM tree_hierarchy
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF<>0
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = PARENT_id
START WITH id = 2
ORDER SIBLINGS BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But In my case this will not work.Your solution requires the root to be known in advance.In my case, db might have multiple roots and i want all the possible leaf to root chains combinations with out duplicates.

Comment: However, there are no duplicates. There are no duplicated rows in the result of your query. It returns the full path for ALL leaves. So, you have to think out of one more condition, that will return only the row you need.
Maybe I didn't understand the question clearly, but try to find these paths not from parent to children but in the oposite direction and start from leaves. I think that's what you need.